# Glow for ViewGroup

Tags: android, layout, shadow

I would like to create a [Box with a Glow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz9WS.png), but I can't get it to work.

How does one achieve this Glow effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use [Customize View Shadows and Outlines](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html#Shadows)

Also you can set shadow colors on Views starting API 28 (Pie) with `android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/myColorPrimary"` and `android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/myColorPrimary"` if you use elevation